# How to combine Wix variables

Tags: wix, wix3, wix3.7

I can use `"!(bind.property.ProductVersion)"` to set for example the UpgradeVersion\@Minimum attribute. Works fine.
But now I want to set that attribute to something like:

```
"!(bind.property.ProductVersion.Major).!(bind.property.ProductVersion.Minor).0.0"
```

But that does not work.
I get this error: The UpgradeVersion/@Maximum attribute's value, '!(bind.property.ProductVersion.Major).!(bind.property.ProductVersion.Minor).0.0', is not a valid version.  Legal version values should look like 'x.x.x.x' where x is an integer from 0 to 65534.

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Regards, Jaap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it appears the version attribute is only allowed to have a single binder variable to replace the whole string. It doesn't support the scenario you describe. However, it seems like it should. You could file a bug at http://wixtoolset.org/bugs

Comment: I mark this as the answer, although not really the one I wanted to hear :-). I hope the 'bug' will be solved soon. And if not I can Always create an extension to solve this problem (http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/extension_development_preprocessor.htm)

Comment: **Or** instead of writing an extension you could help us improve the WiX toolset and fix the bug and contribute to the OSS project. :)  The code you're looking for is `GetAttributeVersionValue()` in `src\wix\CompilerCore.cs`. It's pretty obvious how the single bind variable is supported right now.